# Test Automation Using Ruby Selenium Web Driver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have written quite a few Ruby programs for my clients test automation project.But the problem is my client wants to check the output to his PC without instilling ruby.He is asking me to make one web application where he can select functionality from drop down and run the automation by clicking run button.And after completion the test it will auto generate a test result.Is there any possible way to do so?

Comment: @Russell:Thanks for your help.My problem is i am novice and do not know to use Jenkins and how to ingrate my automation script to Jenkins.
Can you please tell me-"How to setup Jenkins a server and where to integrate my ruby script which can hit virtually from anywhere and trigger selenium script to execute all the functional tests and all your client has to do is hit a "Play" button to execute them."

Answer (score 0):

> He is asking me to make one web application where he can select functionality from drop down and run the automation by clicking run button

A work around to let your client run the current tests without installing the environment on their PC is to use the CI tool [Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/), and a few of the Jenkins plugins such as [CI Reporter](https://github.com/nicksieger/ci_reporter) which is an add-on to Test::Unit and RSpec that allows you to generate XML reports of your test and/or spec runs.

You can set Jenkins up on a server that they can hit virtually from anywhere and trigger a shell / selenium script that can execute all the unit tests and functional tests against the latest build / code, and all your client has to do is hit a "Play" button to execute them.

> And after completion the test it will auto generate a test result.Is there any possible way to do so?

Here are some example images that some of the data Jenkins can export. It's really easy to set up and the community is massive in regards to support.

Screenshots of [Failed Tests Results](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/69764746/top%20level%20view.png) and [Passed Tests Results](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/download/attachments/69764746/scenario.png)

Hope this helps!